# How do I use Vue.use with dynamic imports?

Tags: vue.js

Currently I have

```
import { SchedulePlugin } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-schedule";
Vue.use(SchedulePlugin);
```

I would like to change this to a dynamic import.

I've changed the import to:

```
const { SchedulePlugin } = () => import("@syncfusion/ej2-vue-schedule");
```

but have been unable to find the syntax for the corresponding changes I need to make to `Vue.use`.

What is the correct syntax to use?

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic import syntax you have is for specifying async `components`, where Vue internally resolves them. For Vue plugins, you have to resolve the module yourself before passing it on to `Vue.use()`. The `import()` method returns a `Promise`, so you can `await` the result of the module loading in the context of an `async` function:

```js
const loadPlugins = async () => {
  const { SchedulePlugin } = await import("@syncfusion/ej2-vue-schedule")
  Vue.use(SchedulePlugin)
}

loadPlugins()
```

Note the plugins should be loaded *before* the app to ensure the plugin's effects are available to the app:

```js
loadPlugins().then(() => {
  new Vue({
    render: (h) => h(App)
  }).$mount("#app")
})
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loading-vue-plugins-with-dynamic-import-ktb86)